# Split a string into N length parts

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to split a string, lets say `"abcdef"` into equal parts n characters long. In my case I want into parts 2 characters long.So `"abcdef"` -> `[ab,bc,cd,de,df]`. I see similar questions on here, but the answers use `str.match(/.{1,2}/gi)` and output `[ab,cd,ef]` which isn't what I want.

Comment: could you please explain how that differs from what you do want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the string into separate letters and map over them adding a previous letter in each iteration:

```js
const input = "abcdef"

const result = input
  .split('')
  .map((letter, idx, arr) => arr[idx - 1] + letter)
  .slice(1)

console.log(result)
```

Slice(1) is needed to remove the invalid pair created in the first iteration.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using a simple [`for` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) and [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring):

```js
function foo(input, n) {
  if (input.length < n) {
    throw new Error('n is too large');
  }
  let output = [];
  for(let i = 0; i <= input.length - n; i++) {
    output.push(input.substring(i, i+n));
  }
  return output;
}

console.log(foo('abcdef', 1));
console.log(foo('abcdef', 2));
console.log(foo('abcdef', 3));
console.log(foo('abcdef', 4));
console.log(foo('abcdef', 5));
console.log(foo('abcdef', 6));
console.log(foo('abcdef', 7));
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with `reduce`:

```
let arr = Array.from(str).reduce((a,c,i,s)=>{if (i+n<=s.length) a.push(s.slice(i,i+n)); return a},[]);
```

The idea is to convert the string into an array and then apply `splice(i,i+n)` in a loop.